# How to get rows of specific table and cells of specific row only

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have table with id `parentTable`. Also there is child table in the third column of every row. When i count the length of rows of parent table it gives me sum of rows of parent and child table. Also this happens with the tds. How do i achieve this for getting/iterating rows of parent table only and interating tds of parent rows only. I tried `$('parentTable >tbody>tr')` but not worked for me. Please assist. Below is the sample.

```
   <table id="parentTable"><tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
      <table>
       <tr>
      <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>      
     </table>
  </td>
    </tr>
<td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
       <table>
       <tr>
      <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>      
     </table>
  </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: please share a sample of your html does the parent table has a id or class are you using it in your selector

Comment: also you have used the correct selector for `parentTable` right

Comment: parentTable is an ID or a Class ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Yes I have used correct selector. also there is lot of markup, so i have not posted. But this is what scenario with parent and child table.

Comment: just share a sample... a table with 2 rows and a simple child table where the case can be recreated

Comment: @eraj try using the :nth-child() Selector, you may achieve what you want. Check this out here http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C2WCL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign different classes to the rows (`tr` s) of the parent table, and the child table. And use those classes for selecting them. You can do the same for the cells (`td`s) too.

For example, you if your table looks like -

```
<table class="parentTable">
    <tr class="parentRow">
        <td class="parentCell">Cell 1</td>
        <td class="parentCell">Cell 2</td>
        <td class="parentCell">
            <table class="childTable">
                <tr class="childRow">
                    <td class="childCell">Cell 31</td>
                    <td class="childCell">Cell 32</td>
                    <td class="childCell">Cell 33</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In your jquery, to get just the parent rows and their cells you can use

```
$.each($(".parentRow"), function() {
    $.each($(this).find(".parentCell"), function() {
        //Do Something
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect helped me out :)